# Genymotion and sugar orm

Tags: android, sqlite, genymotion, sugarorm

I'm using sugar orm in my android application and its already in Google Play Store.
Now I want to update my database schema and send an updated apk to Google Play store
However there is a problem while I'm trying to update my schema with following the official documentation of sugar orm.
(Adding version sql files with neccesary alter commands like alter table ....)

For figuring out the problem, I'm looking for the actual sqlite database file in the device, but I am not able to find it in anywhere.
I'm using genymotion emulator as samsung galaxy s6 device , so do you think is it something related with that? Or do you think are there any other problem

Does anyone know how can I find the actual sqlite database file path for sugar orm

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution here

https://gist.github.com/sibeliusseraphini/b060c415604c52c2a94e

So I could pull the db file and then figure out the problem
"Column names must be upper Case"